# Apache zeppelin binding mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I am a bit confused with Zeppelin interpreters' binding mode. I am using Zeppelin 0.7.2, and for what I understand, if I configure an interpreter with an 'isolated' binding mode, then each user gets their own interpreter process. Considering this, I would expect that when one user is running a notebook, the execution should not be affected by some other user restarting the interpreter from one of his/her notebook pages. But that's not the case, the execution ends with 'KeyboardInterrupt'.

Here it explains it perfectly:

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/usage/interpreter/interpreter_binding_mode.html#isolated-mode

But since it's for Zeppelin 0.8.0 I don't know if my only problem is the version I am using. Or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from link you provided isolated mode is per note isolation not per user. 
"Isolated mode runs a separate interpreter **process for each note** in the case of per note scope. So, each note has an absolutely isolated session. (But it is still possible to share objects via ResourcePool)"

So if one user is running note1 and another user restarts interpreter for note 1 it will impact first user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There's the option to enable isolation mode per user and per note at the same time in the interpreter settings. The thing is that even if I only select per note isolation, when a user starts running a notebook and the interpreter is restarted from another notebook (which I would assume is in a different JVM process, so it should not affect it), the first notebook stops running. So I think there's some kind of dependency between interpreter instances....I'm quite lost.